# gostscript error while extracting fonts?

Tags: fonts, ghostscript

Hi here is my script for windows , i am trying to extract fonts from pdf  gs_toolbin_extractFonts.ps is available at [gs_toolbin_extractFonts.ps](http://git.ghostscript.com/?p=ghostpdl.git;a=blob_plain;f=gs/toolbin/extractFonts.ps)

```
    C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.10\bin>gswin32c.exe -q -dExtractSubsets -dNODISPLAY gs_toolbin_extractFonts.ps  -c  d:\anil\telugu\marripalli.pdf
Error: /undefined in d:\anil\telugu\marripalli.pdf
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_p
ush   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1179/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:79/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: No such file or directory
GPL Ghostscript 9.10: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your command line goes "-c filename" -c says 'the following is PostScript, until we get to a -f' so the interpreter tries to treat your filename as PostScript, which not surprisingly fails.

extractfonts.ps doesn't extract text, it extracts fonts, if you want to extract text use the txtwrite device instead.

Comment: sorry i want  to extracts fonts only

Comment: Then you can use extractfonts, but drop the -c switch